# Unable to remove root node from an xml document using linq to xml c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Actullay, I need to get all elements except root node from first xml document and so that I could insert them as child nodes to an element(that has same name as a previous doc's root name) in a new document.
So I have tried various ways to achieve it, one of them is removing the root node of first and then trying to add elements to a new one's as given below:

I have tried the following but could not achieve it.

```
XDocument testDoc = XDocument.Parse(Mydocument);
testDoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "rootName").Select(m=>m).Single().Remove();
var resultDoc = testDoc;
```

The above code is giving me an empty "{}" result.

my xml document looks something like the below one's:

```
 <rootName xsi:schemaLocation="" xmlns:xsi="" xmlns="">
 <main>
 <child>
 </child>
 <anotherchild>
 </anotherchild>
 </main>
 </rootName>
```

And another way is getting all the elements of first document as the following:

```
  var resultDoc = testDoc.Descendants(ns + "rootName").Elements();
```

the above statement is giving me the list of elements in the "testDoc" which
I need to do something like below, I am clueless:

```
 <AnotherDocument xsi:schemaLocation="" xmlns:xsi="" xmlns="">
 <firstNode>
 <rootName>

 <main>
 <child>
 </child>
 <anotherchild>
 </anotherchild>
 </main>

 </rootName>
 </firstNode>
```

Please let me know how to insert those elements in a new document as above if I am correct else let me know the way to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Are you trying to add `main` node to another xml file/string? How that another xml looks like?

Comment: Do your documents have same `xmlns` defined? Also where `anotherchild` came from - is it part of first document, or it existed in AnotherDocument?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please check my updated question above that I have elaborated in detail.

Comment: No, I have some "http://..." link in them. just mocked them. just added them to define my xml document structure. It should be part of my first document sorry if I confuse you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace content of `rootName` element in another document with elements from first document root:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(Mydocument);
var anotherXDoc = XDocument.Load("anotherdata.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://..."; // your xml namespance
var rootName = anotherXDoc.Descendants(ns + "rootName").First();
rootName.ReplaceNodes(xDoc.Root.Elements());
```

Comment: Thank you so much.That is really great. This is exactly what I am looking for. It worked but then I don't know how to update my new document("AnotherDocument") with the updated elements in it. Could you please let me know that one.

Comment: @user1105705 if you want to save updated document to file, then use `anotherXDoc.Save("anotherdata.xml")`

Answer (score 0):

By this page_nodes gets all nodes now you can used all node by for each loop

```
 var page_nodes = from p in xdoc.Descendants.Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "rootName").Select(m=>m).Single().Remove() select p;

foreach (var page_node in page_nodes)
 {
    //Do stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't removing a root node, remove all its child nodes as well? The result you are getting is to be expected I think. You should probably get all the children of the root and copy them to your new document.

Comment: thanks for your response...You are correct. I have elaborated my question above.. please let me know how to resolve it.